# SAS character comparison

Tags: sas

In SAS I have two variables.

```
NEW: 12345678900 
OLD: 2345678900
```

I need a way to see if the last 10 characters in NEW are equal to the last 10 characters in OLD.

I've tried a variety of things, but it keeps flagging everything even when they aren't equal.

Comment: Please add the 'variety of things' that you coded and the log messages you saw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
same_10char_tail = 0;

if length(new) > 9 and length(old) > 9 then
  if substr(new,length(new)-9) = substr(old,length(old)-9) then 
    same_10char_tail=1;
```

The nested `if` prevents a warning that would occur if the value was less than 10 characters long.  Only when both variables are >=10 chars long will `substr` be happy.

Answer (score 1):

You can reverse the strings and use `=:`.  Or use `substrn()` to take the last 9 non-blank characters.

```
data want;
  set have;
  test1=reverse(trim(old)) =: reverse(trim(new));
  test2=substrn(old,length(old)-8) = substrn(new,length(new)-8);
run;
```

Results:

```
Obs    old           new            test1    test2

 1     2345678900    12345678900      1        1
 2     abc           xyz              0        0
```